# Finding the resistance of a practical inductor having its reactive power

Tags: power, inductor, practical

Suppose I have a simple practical inductor as such:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Iz2k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

L is known. R is unknown and we need to find it. The supply frequency (say \$f\$) is known. Also the reactive power on the whole inductor (say \$Q_i\$) is known.

---

Here's my approach. The reactance on the inductive part would be (say \$\chi\$ )

$$\chi = \omega L$$

*(where \$ \omega = 2*\pi*f\$)*. So the impedance triangle and the power triangle would be something like this:

[image: The two triangles]

that angle a is equivalent in both triangles. so this would mean that:

$$\frac{\chi}{R} = \frac{Q_i}{P_i}$$

We don't have \$P_i\$ ...however I have a source that says that the equation is just

$$\frac{\chi}{R} = Q_i$$

and that we can get R. The source doesn't provide steps. Just the equation. What am I doing wrong??

---

Actually I need to solve *(the first part)* of a question. Here's a screenshot of the question and the part of the solution of concern.

[image: for reference]

Comment: If you knew the apparent power you could solve it. Q doesn't equal X/R from what I can tell. Sin(a) = X/R.

Comment: @Andyaka would it make a difference if we're doing our calculations at resonance frequency?

Comment: @Andyaka I've added a screenshot of the question and part of the answer. Maybe I don't understand the question right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther mistake you made was assuming Q meant "reactive power" - it doesn't it's the Q-factor of the coil and quite simply is \$X_L/R\$. Q-factor is something you should look up. Q is sometimes called quality factor. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) wiki page. It's embodied in an RLC resonant tuned circuit for instance by this formula: -

[image]

And, for just the inductor on its own is simply \$X_L/R\$

Comment: Think carefully about this LOL